# Uninstall PHP completely from Ubuntu

Tags: php

Could some one tell me how to uninstall PHP completely from Ubuntu? I have problems with installing MySql because of this. There seem to be some unmet dependencies. I think I messed up with the whole installation procedure. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: There is a Ubuntu-specific SE site you could try. http://askubuntu.com

Comment: In fact, it has already been answered on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-compelety-remove-php

Answer (score 3):

This is not a easy way to answer. First we have to know how to installed the PHP at first place.

But for every way, this must work.
Search what kind of package you have installed using

```
aptitude search php5
```

and remove them accordingly using `purge` command

```
sudo aptitude purge php5-package1 ...so on
```

Comment: I wanted to install LAMP and I tried installing Apache, Mysql and php manually. while installing I messed up with Mysql. so I thought i will remove all of them and make fresh installations. I get the following error when I try to uninstall php:

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Ubuntu, but: sudo apt-get remove php* should work.

Comment: I know this is old, but to anyone who finds this, do NOT do this unless you want to completely screw up your server...

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get remove --purge